# How to delete multiple rows with 2 columns as composite primary key in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, delete-row, composite-primary-key, sql-delete

I need to delete some rows in a SQLite table with two columns as primary key, like this:

```
DELETE FROM apt_lang 
WHERE (apt_fk, apt_lang_fk) NOT IN ((42122,"en"),(42123,"es"),(42123,"en"))
```

This works on Oracle and MySQL but not in SQLite.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

First, find out which rows you want to delete.
The easiest way is with a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM apt_lang
JOIN (SELECT 42122 AS apt_fk, 'en' AS apt_lang_fk UNION ALL
      SELECT 42123          , 'es'                UNION ALL
      SELECT 42123          , 'en'                         )
USING (apt_fk, apt_lang_fk)
```

To use this with a DELTE, either check with EXISTS for a match:

```
DELETE FROM apt_lang
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM apt_lang AS a2
                  JOIN (SELECT 42122 AS apt_fk, 'en' AS apt_lang_fk UNION ALL
                        SELECT 42123          , 'es'                UNION ALL
                        SELECT 42123          , 'en'                         )
                  USING (apt_fk, apt_lang_fk)
                  WHERE apt_fk      = apt_lang.apt_fk
                    AND apt_lang_fk = apt_lang.apt_lang_fk)
```

or get the [ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)s of the subquery and check against those:

```
DELETE FROM apt_lang
WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT apt_lang.rowid
                    FROM apt_lang
                    JOIN (SELECT 42122 AS apt_fk, 'en' AS apt_lang_fk UNION ALL
                          SELECT 42123          , 'es'                UNION ALL
                          SELECT 42123          , 'en'                         )
                    USING (apt_fk, apt_lang_fk))
```

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but this looks awful. Can you really not delete based on composite keys in SQLite?

Comment: @gwg No, I do not have a better solution up my sleeve.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
DELETE FROM apt_lang WHERE (apt_fk, apt_lang_fk) NOT IN (VALUES (42122,"en"),(42123,"es"),(42123,"en"))
```

Comment: Cool, and this also works on PostgreSQL (at least on Postgres 12.1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to delete rows from SQLite based on a subquery that builds on multiple columns. This can be done with SQLite's concatenate **"||"** operator. It might help to show an example.

**Setup:**

```
create table a (x,y); 
insert into a values ('A','B');
insert into a values ('A','C');

create table b (x,y);
insert into b values ('A','C');
insert into b values ('A','X');
```

**Show Tables:**

```
select * from a;
A|B
A|C

select * from b;
A|C
A|X
```

Assuming you want to delete from table **a** rows where column x and column y don't match with table **b**, the following select will accomplish that.

```
delete from a where x||y not in (select a.x||a.y from a,b where a.x=b.x and a.y=b.y);
```

**Result:**

```
select * from a;
A|B
```

**Summary**

This relies on concatenating several columns into one with the **"||"** operator.  Note, it will work on calculated values too, but it might require casting the values.  So, just a few conversions to note with the **"||"** operator...

```
 select 9+12|| 'test';
 21 -- Note we lost 'test'

 select cast(9+12 as text)|| 'test';
 21test -- Good!  'test' is there.
```